# Graphics.DrawImageについて

Tags: c++, winapi

LayerdWindowにおいて、`Graphics.DrawImage`に渡した画像が透過処理されているときに、画像の表示先に重なる背後のエリアが拡大して表示されるのはなぜなのでしょうか？（日本語下手ですみません）

Comment: Gdiplusですかね(質問)。どのオーバーライドかも明示しましょう。可能であれば症状のキャプチャー画像を追加してみてはどうでしょう。